# Regarding: PHP incrementing counter

Tags: php

I am currently having trouble building up a reference number. I want this reference number to increment as a new customer is being added for example.

```
<?php
  $prefix = "CUST-"; 
  $DateConv = "2006-";
  $reference = "CUST-2006-0001"; 
?>
```

The $reference will be the final set after the automation build for the first customer. Let's say the 15th customer has been created. Then this customer's reference must be CUS-2006-0015.

The $DateConv variable, I will just retrieve the current date and convert it to that format.

Can anyone please assist with this request, please?

Comment: If this is database related, why would you want to increment like that? Why not just use an auto_increment'ed column?

Comment: Can you please explain what your actual problem with this is? At which point exactly are you stuck?

Comment: How do you know how many customers there are?

Comment: I don't want to use and an auto-increment table because when I customer is being created, I want the system to build a reference number for the customer, that you can use for unique searching as well.

For example: `$num = 9;

                       printf("%04d", $num);`

I want to increment that value 0009 to 0010, if that makes sense?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a loop to get the result you want,

```
$i=1;
foreach ($reference as $var){

  echo $var;
  $i ++;

}
```

Comment: I used the following code and will implement it into a loop.

`<?php

$num = 10;
$paddedNum = sprintf("%04d", $num);
$paddedNum = $paddedNum;
$numTot = sprintf("%04d", ++$num);
echo $numTot;`

Thank you for the help.